# Paper.js | calling document.body.style.opacity from within a paperscript

Tags: javascript, css, html, paperjs

I have a site which is essentially one big canvas image. At the moment, when the body is loaded it starts to fade in through this code:

```
<body onLoad="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
```

However I'd like to call this from within my paperscript as there are times when the body will start fading in before the image is loaded from within the paperscript (image is retrieved from a website).

If this is not possible, would someone be able to point me in the direction of bringing an image in and then passing it to the paperscript without the image being displayed on the site initially?

[Link for reference](https://test.stefanlogue.co.uk/)

Comment: Does placing it in `raster.on( 'load', function() {} )` work?

Comment: I tried to place it in there initially as a javascript function rather than just exactly which I typed above, which has now solved my problem! Thanks, bit of a brain fart moment from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try placing it in `raster.on( 'load', function() {} );`.

```
raster.on( 'load', function() {
  document.body.style.opacity = 1;
  // your code 
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know what made me change the expression to a javascript version of it when I tried that the first time!